# Updating entire dojox.grid.datagrid row

Tags: javascript, datagrid, dojo, grid

I've been trying to update the entire row of my grid, but having issues. I *am* able to update a single cell (if it doesn't have a formatter), but I would like to be able to update the entire row. Alternatively, I could update the column, but I'm not able to get it working if it has a formatter.

Here is the code that I'm using to update the grid:

```
grid.store.fetch({query : { some_input : o.some_input },
    onItem : function (item ) {
        dataStore.setValue(item, 'input', '123'); //works!
        dataStore.setValue(item, '_item', o);     //doesn't work!
    }
});
```

And the structure of my grid:

```
structure: [
    { type: "dojox.grid._CheckBoxSelector"},
    [[{ name: "Field1", field: "input", width:"25%"}
     ,{ name: "Field2", field: "another_input", width:"25%"}
     ,{ name: "Field3", field: "_item", formatter:myFormatter, width:"25%"}
     ,{ name: "Field4", field: "_item", formatter:myOtherFormatter, width:"25%"}
    ]]
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Got some information in the #dojo freenode channel from 'tk' who kindly put together a fiddle showing the proper way to do this, most noteably putting an idProperty on the memoryStore and overwriting the data: http://jsfiddle.net/few3k7b8/2/

```
    var memoryStore = new Memory({
      data: [{
         alienPop: 320000,
         humanPop: 56000,
         planet: 'Zoron'
      }, {
         alienPop: 980940,
         humanPop: 56052,
         planet: 'Gaxula'
      }, {
         alienPop: 200,
         humanPop: 500,
         planet: 'Reiutsink'
      }],
      idProperty: "planet"
    });
```

And then when we want to update:

```
    memoryStore.put(item, {
        overwrite: true
    });
```

Remember that item has to have a field 'planet', and it should be the same as one of our existing planets in order to overwrite that row.